# BQ51051B or BQ51050B communicate but won't charge

Tags: power-supply, circuit-design, charger, wireless-charging

I was building this wireless IC charger using BQ51051BRHLR circuit and when I connected the coil to the transmitter the output on Pin Rect shows a voltage of 10 V but the battery won't charge.
Here you can find my circuit I also tried to change the RECT resistor to 42k2 like the EVM design it gives better results but the problem remains.
I tried different coils of 12, 16 and 27 uH but the problem still remains
Does anyone have an idea how to fix it?

[image]

[image: Circuit BQ51051B]

Comment: What signals do we see on the scope picture?

Comment: What voltage do you see on Vchg? what about EN2?

Comment: The signal on the scope is for the Rect pin.

Comment: On Vchg i detected the voltage of the battery wich is 3.7-3.8v. On EN2 its 3.3V which is normal to let the wireless charger work

Answer (score 0):

I did solve the problem, the TS pin was not welded properly so the resistor 10kohm was not connected to the IC hence not letting the IC to charge properly